# Simple checkout with braintree on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, braintree

I'm trying to create a simple checkout using braintree.

I have a sandbox account with them and have already setup `braintree.rb` with my `merchant_id`, `public_key` and `private_key`.

My `transactions` controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    gon.client_token = generate_client_token
  end

  def create
    nonce = params[:payment_method_nonce]
    result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      :amount => "100.00",
      :payment_method_nonce => params[:payment_method_nonce]
    )

    if result.success?
        puts result.transaction.status
          flash[:notice] = "Transaction successful"
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          flash.now[:alert] = result.errors.to_json
          gon.client_token = generate_client_token
          render :new
        end
  end

  private

  def generate_client_token
    Braintree::ClientToken.generate
  end
end
```

My view:

```
<h1>Braintree transaction</h1>

<%= form_tag transactions_path, role: 'form', id: 'test' do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'Cardholder name' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'Cardholder name', nil, name: nil, placeholder: 'Cardholder name', data: {'braintree-name' => 'cardholder_name'}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'Card number' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'Card number', nil, name: nil, placeholder: 'Card number', data: {'braintree-name' => 'number'}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'Cvv number' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'Cvv number', nil, name: nil, placeholder: 'CVV', data: {'braintree-name' => 'cvv'}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'Month' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'Month', nil, name: nil, placeholder: 'Month in MM format', data: {'braintree-name' => 'expiration_month'}, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= label_tag 'Year' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'Year', nil, name: nil, placeholder: 'Year in YY format', data: {'braintree-name' => 'expiration_year'}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%=submit_tag 'Charge', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  </div>

<% end %>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
// We generated a client token for you so you can test out this code
// immediately. In a production-ready integration, you will need to
// generate a client token on your server (see section below).

braintree.setup(gon.client_token, "custom", {
  id: "test"
});

// braintree.setup(clientToken, "custom", {id: "test"});
</script>
```

Notice that I have a line in the controller `flash.now[:alert] = result.errors.to_json` `to_json`. Once I submit a form I get a bunch of errors but the one that really grabs my attention is:

`code":"91569","attribute":"payment_method_nonce","message":"payment_method_nonce does not contain a valid payment instrument type.`

[image]

EDIT:

edited my `create` action to add `puts nonce` as requested in comments:

```
def create
    nonce = params[:payment_method_nonce]
    puts nonce
    puts 'before this is nonce'
    result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      :amount => "100.00",
      :payment_method_nonce => params[:payment_method_nonce]
    )
    puts result
    puts result.success?

    if result.success?
        puts result.transaction.status
          flash[:notice] = "Transaction successful"
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          # flash[:alert] = "Transaction error: #{result.errors}"
          flash[:alert] = result.errors.to_json
          gon.client_token = generate_client_token
          render :new
        end
  end
```

I get the following result when I `post`

[image]

EDIT:

Was able to use their `dropin` form and transaction was successful using their credit card system, but when you try to login to paypal it gives the error.

[image]

Comment: I work at Braintree. Would you be able to add a `puts nonce` somewhere in `#create` after `nonce` has been set? I would be curious to see what value is being passed in.

Comment: Hi @BillR I've added in the question the requests you asked me. Sorry for not replying before, I was on small vacations.

Comment: Thanks for that extra information @Johhan. We usually see this behavior when no credit card data is included in the form you are submitting. We have a [list of credit card numbers](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing#credit-card-numbers) that can be used in sandbox for this purpose. You can enter any value for the expiration date, as long as it is in the future.

If you need further assistance with this issue, I recommend emailing our support team at support@braintreepayments.com for more help.

Comment: @BillR thanks, I was able to use one of your credit cards and they worked, now, what I am getting errors are in the paypal function for the `dropin`, I try to connect but it always returns as an "error occurred, try again". I will email you guys, thanks!

Comment: @Johhan did you ever get a problem where if you had an error and then `render :new` the drop in ui would appear ?